# Only if Tomcat deploys in a certain order: Could not initialize class org.apache.wss4j.stax.setup.WSSec

Tags: java, tomcat, cxf, wss4j

I have searched for a solution on the Internet before posting, I found nothing that helps my case.

I have a Tomcat (9.0.5) instance that contains two webapps, let's call them webapp `foo` and webapp `bar`. These webapps are compiled using Maven 3.5.3.

`foo` includes a Maven dependency: `org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-stax:jar:2.2.4`. This Java library is also included in `foo`'s `WEB-INF/lib` directory, packed inside its own .war file (Maven build process seems to work fine). `foo` uses CXF 3.3.5 and WSS4J 2.2.4.

Webapp `bar` does not include `org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-stax:jar:2.2.4`, instead.

I must deploy these two webapps under the same Tomcat instance, so I upload them under `${catalina.base}/webapps` and then I run Tomcat.

If Tomcat deploys `foo` webapp first, nothing goes wrong.

If Tomcat deploys `bar` webapp first, I got the following error instead:

```
Could not load or register WS-SecurityPolicy related classes. Please check that (the correct version of) Apache WSS4J is on the classpath: Could not initialize class org.apache.wss4j.stax.setup.WSSec
```

I am going crazy on this. Based on other topics I found way to enforce Tomcat deployment order, but honestly I do not like that solution. In my opinion, that is a wrong approach.

I do not have set customization on Tomcat classpath, I do not understand why this happens. You can fine below the results of `mvn dependency:tree` of `foo` and `bar`.

BAR:

```
[INFO] -------------------< bar >--------------------
[INFO] Building bar
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.3:tree (default-cli) @ bar-web ---
[INFO] bar.modules:bar-web:war:5.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- bar.modules:bar-core:jar:5.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- bar.modules:bar-jpa:jar:5.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.3.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.6.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.8.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.7:runtime
[INFO] |  +- bar.modules:firmaremota-rest-core:jar:1.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:4.3.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.0.CR2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.helger:peppol-smp-client:jar:5.2.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.helger:peppol-commons:jar:5.2.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.helger:ph-security:jar:8.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.helger:ph-xml:jar:8.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.helger:ph-json:jar:8.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.helger:ph-xsds-xmldsig:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- dnsjava:dnsjava:jar:2.1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.helger:ph-httpclient:jar:8.8.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.helger:ph-http:jar:8.8.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- com.helger:ph-network:jar:8.8.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.helger:ph-settings:jar:8.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.helger:peppol-directory-businesscard:jar:0.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.helger:ph-commons:jar:8.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.helger:ph-jaxb:jar:8.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.helger:ph-datetime:jar:8.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.60:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:jar:2.4.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.metro:webservices-rt:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.metro:webservices-api:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2-b03:runtime
[INFO] |  +- no.difi.oxalis:oxalis-document-sniffer:jar:4.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- no.difi.vefa:peppol-icd:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- no.difi.vefa:peppol-common:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- no.difi.vefa:peppol-sbdh:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- no.difi.commons:commons-sbdh:jar:0.9.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:28.1-jre:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.google.guava:failureaccess:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:jar:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:jar:2.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:jar:1.18:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.oracle:ojdbc16:jar:11.2.0.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.mail:javax.mail-api:jar:1.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.mail:javax.mail:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:3.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sourceforge.saxon:saxon:jar:9.1.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sourceforge.saxon:saxon:jar:dom:9.1.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk15on:jar:1.60:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.60:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.passay:passay:jar:1.5.0:compile
[INFO] +- bar.modules:bar-entity:jar:5.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] +- bar.modules:bar-job:jar:5.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- c3p0:c3p0:jar:0.9.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- bar.modules:oxalis-bar-integration:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:3.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.2.9.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:jar:3.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-acl:jar:3.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.2.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.2.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons.spring:jaxws-spring:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.xbean:xbean-spring:jar:3.14:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] +- javax:javaee-web-api:jar:6.0:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.16:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.pdfbox:fontbox:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.webjars:bootstrap:jar:3.3.7-1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.webjars:jquery:jar:1.11.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.webjars:jquery-ui:jar:1.12.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.webjars:jquery-ui-themes:jar:1.12.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.webjars:datatables:jar:1.10.13:compile
[INFO] +- org.webjars:html5shiv:jar:3.7.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.webjars:respond:jar:1.4.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.webjars:font-awesome:jar:4.6.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.webjars.bower:tinymce:jar:4.4.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.webjars.bower:moment:jar:2.18.1:compile
[INFO] +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.12.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.9.5:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:1.0:test
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
```

FOO:

```
[INFO] -------------------< foo >--------------------
[INFO] Building foo
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ bar-war ---
[INFO] foo.modules:bar-war:war:1.0.0
[INFO] +- foo.modules:bar-notier-core:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.17.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.17.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-guice:jar:1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.sun.jersey:jersey-servlet:jar:1.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- foo.modules:bar-notier-integration:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-dbcp2:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- no.difi.oxalis:bar-outbound:jar:4.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- no.difi.oxalis:bar-document-sniffer:jar:4.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- no.difi.vefa:peppol-icd:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- no.difi.vefa:peppol-lookup:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- no.difi.commons:commons-busdox:jar:0.9.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- no.difi.commons:commons-bdx:jar:0.9.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- dnsjava:dnsjava:jar:2.1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- no.difi.vefa:peppol-security:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- no.difi.commons:commons-certvalidator:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- net.klakegg.pkix:pkix-ocsp:jar:0.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- no.difi.oxalis:bar-commons:jar:4.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.inject.extensions:guice-servlet:jar:4.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.26:compile
[INFO] |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- foo.modules:bar-rest:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.6:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.10:compile
[INFO] |     \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.11:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:4.0.1:provided
[INFO] +- no.difi.oxalis:bar-as4:jar:4.1.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:jar:3.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex:jar:1.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:jar:1.2.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:jar:5.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:jar:2.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-security:jar:3.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-soap:jar:3.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:jar:3.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-wsdl:jar:3.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-features-logging:jar:3.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:jar:3.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-xml:jar:3.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-simple:jar:3.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-addr:jar:3.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:jar:3.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-policy:jar:3.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-security:jar:3.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-security-saml:jar:3.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:2.10.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-stax:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-bindings:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-policy-stax:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-common:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:jar:2.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-saml-impl:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-profile-api:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.opensaml:opensaml-core:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     \- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-saml-api:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-xmlsec-api:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.opensaml:opensaml-soap-api:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-security-impl:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.opensaml:opensaml-security-api:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     \- org.cryptacular:cryptacular:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-xmlsec-impl:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- net.shibboleth.utilities:java-support:jar:7.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-xacml-impl:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.opensaml:opensaml-xacml-api:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-xacml-saml-impl:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.opensaml:opensaml-xacml-saml-api:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jasypt:jasypt:jar:1.9.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-dom:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-policy:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.neethi:neethi:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- foo.modules:bar-notier-rest-server:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- no.difi.oxalis:bar-inbound:jar:4.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:27.0.1-jre:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.guava:failureaccess:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:jar:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:jar:1.17:compile
[INFO] |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.10.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- no.difi.oxalis:bar-as2:jar:4.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk15on:jar:1.57:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.57:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.57:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.opentracing.contrib:opentracing-web-servlet-filter:jar:0.2.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.opentracing:opentracing-api:jar:0.33.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- io.opentracing:opentracing-util:jar:0.31.0:compile
[INFO] +- foo.modules:bar-quartz:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- c3p0:c3p0:jar:0.9.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- foo.modules:bar-persist:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.mail:javax.mail-api:jar:1.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.quartz-scheduler:quartz-jobs:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- no.difi.oxalis:bar-api:jar:4.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- no.difi.vefa:peppol-common:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.26:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.inject:guice:jar:4.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- no.difi.vefa:peppol-mode:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.typesafe:config:jar:1.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- no.difi.vefa:peppol-sbdh:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- no.difi.commons:commons-sbdh:jar:0.9.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- no.difi.vefa:peppol-evidence:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.zipkin.brave:brave:jar:5.6.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.zipkin.zipkin2:zipkin:jar:2.14.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-reporter:jar:2.8.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-sender-urlconnection:jar:2.7.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.opentracing:opentracing-noop:jar:0.33.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.opentracing.contrib:opentracing-apache-httpclient:jar:0.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.opentracing.contrib:opentracing-spanmanager:jar:0.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.opentracing.brave:brave-opentracing:jar:0.33.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.4:provided
[INFO] \- org.kohsuke.metainf-services:metainf-services:jar:1.8:provided
```

Any further help is truly appreciate. Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

Based on [Konstantin Pribluda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/683735/konstantin-pribluda) suggestion I added this in my `${catalina.base}/conf/context.xml`:

```
    <Loader delegate="true" />
```

After this, I got the following error:

```
Could not load or register WS-SecurityPolicy related classes. Please check that (the correct version of) Apache WSS4J is on the classpath: org/apache/xml/security/exceptions/XMLSecurityException
```

It seems to be the same error, but on another class.

Answer (score 0):

Could be problem with delegation and classloader precedence.   In java class resolves own dependencies  from own classloader, and higher up in hierarchy.  This can lead to classes from your application being ignored even if theyare included in  war.   Try to play around with delegate  setting of classloader.  Detailed explanation:

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help. I changed `Loader delegate="true"`. I got the same error on a different class: `Could not load or register WS-SecurityPolicy related classes. Please check that (the correct version of) Apache WSS4J is on the classpath: org/apache/xml/security/exceptions/XMLSecurityException`

Comment: usually you should have xml related classes bundled with your webapp -   servlet container may have own version of  them which would be incompatible with  yours.